# How to make dynamic tab view screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add tabs in my react native app. Here on tab i want to show all the data coming from an api. This gives a array of `string`. And when user click on any tab it should show respective data. Here is an example image.

Here below header I want to display the array of string coming from the ap.
Below the search field I want to display the data which is coming from different api.

I am using a package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view  . I am not sure how to achieve this with this.

[image: state Image]

> Here is the code I have

```
import { TabView, SceneMap } from "react-native-tab-view";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getAllState } from "../../actions/hubActions";

interface CommunityMemberProps {
  getStates: () => void;
  allStates: [];
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scene: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

const FirstRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: "#ff4081" }]} />
);

const SecondRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: "#673ab7" }]} />
);

const initialLayout = { width: Dimensions.get("window").width };

const CommunityMember = ({ getStates, allStates }: CommunityMemberProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getStates();   
  }, []);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState<string>("");
  const handleChangeText = (text: string) => {
    setSearchText(text);
  };
  console.log("allStates", allStates);  <-- this gives data ["India", "newDelhi"]

  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: "First", title: "First" },
    { key: "Second", title: "Second" },
  ]);


  const renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: FirstRoute,
    second: SecondRoute,
  });
  return (
    <TabView
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      initialLayout={initialLayout}
    />
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
  return {
    allStates: state.hub.allStates,
  };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  getStates: () => dispatch(getAllState()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CommunityMember);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using redux this can be easily done. Whenever you select a tab update the redux state with the tab selected. Keep the component same for all tabs and retrieve the tab from redux state using mapStateToProps and fetch data dynamically and useEffect or componentDidMount() hook.